# A question regarding $L^1(R)\cap L^2(R)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Does $L^1(R)\cap L^2(R)$ have finite or infinite corank in $L^2(R)$?
I guess the latter is the case but I have never seen this discussed, and would like to see a simple proof.

Comment: The family $f_s(x)=(1+|x|)^{-s}$ for $\frac12 <s<1$ spans an infinite-dimensional subspace with trivial intersection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a Banach space in possession of a continuous and dense  inclusion in a strictly larger Banach space must have infinite co-dimension in it. This  is  also the case of 
 $$L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}),\ \|\cdot\|_1+\|\cdot\|_2 \longrightarrow  L^1(\mathbb{R}) ,\ \|\cdot\|_1 . $$

Comment: (a consequence of the Open Mapping Theorem)